# What's is the difference between Array.of(n) , Array(n) and array = [n]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

As the title, i'm wondering what's the difference between this 3 methods of initialization an array.

I'm actually more interested in the new Array.of() method provided from ES6, why they feel the needs of implements that?

Comment: i already saw it, maybe my question was unclear i'm looking for a practical explaination of the usecases instead of a simple docs cut & paste. @AmmarCSE thank you for it anyway

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Array constructor can be called in two ways: a list of values to be used as values for array elements, or with a single numeric value giving the initial length:

```
var myArray = new Array("hello", "world"); // 2 elements
var otherArray = new Array(100); // 100 elements, all empty
```

Because there's an ambiguity when just one number is passed, that old API is considered badly designed. Thus, there's `Array.of()`, which is the same as the first option for the Array constructor:

```
var otherArray = Array.of(100); // 1 element
```

The third way to make an array is with an array initialization expression:

```
var otherArray = [100]; // 1 element
```

The array instances that are created by each of the above are functionally equivalent and completely interchangeable.

One more thing: why does `Array.of()` have to exist, given that we can use the array initialization expression? Well, `Array.of()` is a function, so it can be used as a value applied in functional-style programming. You can (as a slightly dumb example) copy an array with:

```
var copy = Array.of.apply(Array, original);
```

One reason that's dumb is that there's also (in ES2015) `Array.from()` to do the same thing:

```
var copy = Array.from(original);
```

That works on any sort of iterable original, so it's a good way to turn `arguments` or a NodeList into an array.

The [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) has documentation on `Array.of()`. The constructor and the array initializer form have been around since forever, so any JavaScript reference will cover those (though possibly without reference to `Array.of()`).

Comment: @thefourtheye oh shoot you're right :) I'd have to do it by making a bound version of `.apply()` (to `.of`) and then bind that to `Array` and that's a little too weird for a pointless example.

Comment: we could even add some reference links to your answer just to make it more complete. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126) seems useful @Pointy

Comment: Good idea. It's also worth noting that as of now InternetExplorer doesn't support the new ES2015 methods.

Comment: Exactly tomorrow IE will not be supported anymore :)

Comment: @StefanoSaitta right, but Edge doesn't support the features either.

Comment: It will support it instead. Edge13 an even Edge12, have a look: [compatibility table for EDGE13](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#edge13)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100391/discussion-between-stefano-saitta-and-pointy).

Comment: Oh, well that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.of(2)` will create an array with the element 2.

```
var temp = Array.of(2); // temp = [2]
```

`Array(2)` will create an array of 2 elements.

```
var temp = new Array(2); // temp = [undefined, undefined]
```

`temp = [2]` will create an array with the element 2.

```
var temp = [2]; // temp = [2]
```